# RODBC to SQL using credentials file (as opposed to clear text)

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

So this works:

```
odbcConnect("TestDB", "admin", "password")
```

but I dont want the username and pwd in clear text.  I figured simply write the credentials to a text file and import that file for use with:

```
odbcConnect(textFile)
```

Saving the credentials and calling readLines(textFile) produces a string with escape characters that throws the connections:

```
"odbcConnect(\"TestDB\", \"admin\", \"password\")"
```

I've tried legion of escape characters in the text file and also tried creating a string using paste but the result always comes back to a version of the line above.  Anyone got a workaround or safer way to connect to SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the variables in a separate .r file.
`username = yourusername
password = yourpassword
dsn = yourDB`

In the script where you connect the ODBC you can then call the script that defines those variables.
 `source("variables.r")`

Comment: That makes sense ... I should have / wish I'd thought of that! Thanks for taking the time - was driving me nuts.

Comment: I took it a step further and simply source a connection to the database script, then the variables never enter the session.